# How to get a boolean value into a SELECT operation based on another table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables: `Message` and `Attachments` (which represent entity types that have a one-to-many relationship) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE message (
    messageId ..., 
    [from]..., 
    [to]..., 
    subject..., 
    body...
);

CREATE TABLE attachments (
    messageId..., 
    filename...
);
```

I want to SELECT the basic message data and include a bit column to denote whether the message has attachments or not. I am trying to use EXISTS in the operation shown below:

```
SELECT  
M.*,
hasAttachments = EXISTS(SELECT AttachmentId 
                          FROM Attachment 
                         WHERE messageId = M.messageId),
FROM Message M
```

But this doesn't work - What's the way to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it with a CASE statement:

```
select
    m.*,
    hasAttachments = CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * from Attachment where messageId = M.messageId) then 1 else 0 end
from Message M
```

or

```
select distinct 
    m.*,
    hasAttachments = CASE WHEN a.AttachmentId is not null then 1 else 0 end
from Message m
left join Attachment a on a.MessageId = m.MessageId
```

Comment: The 2nd one would require an aggregate/distinct because it's zero to many

Comment: It's a left join.. what am I missing? I wrote it without any sql server in front, so I'm sure I might make a mistake, but can't see it now :).

Comment: many attachments for one message would give many output rows. When one is expected. Your first construct avoids that. I used CROSS APPLY not LEFT JOIN. Note: our first solutions do similar but your EXISTS is more efficient than my COUNT.

Comment: @gbn: i read that in sql2005 onward the count and exists are the same because count is treated like exists: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2007/08/27/if-exists-select-vs-if-select-count-1-0.aspx

Comment: @kacalapy: probably, havem't tested myself. However, EXISTS is cleaner. I don't tend to use CASE..EXISTS, that's all, because I find subqueries in the SELECT sometimes confusing. That's a personal thing though

Answer (score 3):

```
select  
    M.*,
   CAST(select COUNT(*) from Attachment A where A.messageId = M.messageId) AS bit) AS hasAttachments,
FROM Message M
```

or

```
select  
    M.*,
   CAST(hasAttachments AS bit) AS hasAttachments,
FROM
  Message M
  CROSS APPLY
  (select COUNT(*) AS hasAttachments
   from Attachment A
    where A.messageId = M.messageId) A2
```

Comment: How are the two options as far as performance? is one better?

Comment: probably the same... you'd have to test

Comment: I like this, and you can even avoid a cast to bit if you use `select count(distinct 1)` in the cross apply.

Comment: @AJ01: it'll still be int. I went for explicit bit type instead of just 0 or 1

Comment: True enough, fair point.